# trying to use djongo engine to connect to documentdb database using ssh tunnel

Tags: django, mongodb, deployment, aws-documentdb

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: namespace name generated from index name is too long, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'code': 67, 'errmsg': 'namespace name generated from index name is too long', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1684956028, 1)}

i'm trying to use djongo engine to connect to documentdb database using ssh tunnel

Answer (score 0):

The error is for something else, the maximum length for the index name, so it looks that you are able to connect. See the [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits-naming_constraints) page, the index name length is limited to 63 characters. Specify the index name explicitly in your code.